# How to convert date into same format?

Tags: php, time

I want to get the $registratiedag and count a couple of days extra, but I always get stuck on the fact that it needs to be a UNIX timestamp? I did some google-ing, but I really don't get it.

I hope someone can help me figure this out. This is what I got so far.

```
$registratiedag = $oUser['UserRegisterDate'];
$today = strtotime('$registratiedag + 6 days');

echo $today;            
echo $registratiedag;

echo date('Y-m-d', $today);
```

There's obviously something wrong with the `strtotime('$registratiedag + 6 days');` part, because I always get 1970-01-01

Comment: yeah that's not a valid way to call strtotime...

Comment: What does `$registratiedag` contain?

Comment: $registratieday contains '2011-05-22' .. And no, I know that's not the right way, but I don't know what is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
// Store as a timestamp
$registratiedag = strtotime($oUser['UserRegisterDate']);
$new_date = strtotime('+6 days', $registratiedag);

// You'll need to format for printing $new_date
echo date('Y-m-d', $new_date);

// I think you want to compare $new_date against
// today's date. I'd recommend a string comparison here,
// As time() includes the time as well
// time() is implied as the second argument to date,
// But we'll put it anyways just to be clearer 
if( date('Y-m-d', $new_date) == date('Y-m-d', time()) ) {
  // The dates are equal, do something here
}
else if($new_date < time()) {
  // if the new date is earlier than today
}
// etc.
```

First it converts `$registratiedag` to a timestamp, then it adds 6 days

**EDIT**: You probably should change `$today` to something less misleading like `$modified_date` or something

Comment: Yeah, I got it working now, thanks. But now I want to compare the dates.. so if $registratiedag == $today ... but that doesn't work :s

Comment: @KimWouters I've updated my code to best show what I believe you're trying to accomplish. Let me know if this is what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

try:

$today = strtorime($registratiedag);
$today += 86400 * 6; // seconds in 1 day * 6 days

at least one of your problems is that PHP does not expand variables in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$today = strtotime("$registratiedag + 6 days"); 
//use double quotes and not single quotes when embedding a php variable in a string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include the value of variable `$registratiedag` right into the text passed as parameter of `strtotime`, you have to enclose that parameter with `"`, not with `'`.

Comment: Ok, fixed it! Thanks a lot! So now I got `$today = strtotime("$registratiedag + 4 days");`, and it works just fine. :)